# How to execute a certain method after a time delay?

Tags: java, android

I have a class like this `Render`:

```
public class Render {
    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask;


    @Override
    public void refresh() {
        if (timerTask != null)
            timerTask.cancel();
        timerTask = new LoadTask();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000);
    }

    private class LoadTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //request the server
        }
    }
}
```

The `refresh` method may be called very frequently, but the job to be done inside the `refresh` is a little heavy, it have to request something from the server, so I tried to make this method execute after a delay.

But as shown, a new `LoadTask` instance will be created once this method got called, is this a waste of memory in android?

So I wonder if any idea to fix it?

Comment: what's exactly the issue?

Comment: What exactly do you want to "fix"?

Comment: The `refresh` method is called too frequently, then many instance of `LoadTask` will be created, I am afraid this is a waste of memory. I am not sure if this is the final choice.

Comment: Of course, creating new object(in your case it) needs memory. Though there will be only one object with non-null reference, GC doesn't run every second. So creating new object every time `refresh()` method calls is a bad idea. To fix it, you should initialize `timerTask` in constuctor method.

Answer (score 2):

You will try this one to execute the task with the delay

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                //Your task it will execute at 1 time only...

                }
            }, 5000);//5 seconds delay and you can change the delay  time...
```

It will execute the thread at ever 10 seconds like as a loop function...

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Your logic it will repeating you task ever 10 seconds....

            }
        }, 5000, 5000);
```

Comment: What library is the `Handler` class in?

Comment: Handler is a default android class file. which is located in android.os.Handler

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just initialise the TimerTask in the constructor of Render Class. Like this

```
public class Render {
    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask;

    public Render()
    {
        timerTask = new LoadTask();         
    }

    //....

}
```

And then just use the reference in Refresh function. This should solve your problem :)

Comment: But once I cancel a `TimerTask`, I can not schedule it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java [Executors, included in version 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html). You reuse the thread instance and the LoadTask instance.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Render {

    private final LoadTask yourDelayedTask;
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    private static final long DELAY_MS = 1000;

    public Render() {
        scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        yourDelayedTask = new LoadTask();
    }

    private ScheduledFuture<?> lastScheduledTask;

    public void refresh() {
        if (lastScheduledTask != null && !lastScheduledTask.isCancelled() || !lastScheduledTask.isDone()) { // Review this logic
            lastScheduledTask.cancel(true);
        }
        lastScheduledTask = scheduler.schedule(yourDelayedTask, DELAY_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }

    private class LoadTask implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // request the server
        }
    }
}
```